# Get different query back based on a condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a hard time with sql and probably this will look stupid but it shows what I am trying to achieve.

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN ( ( SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE = condition ) IS NULL ) THEN
      SELECT 'No result'::varchar
   ELSE
      SELECT
         val_1,
         val_2,
         val_3
      FROM
         table_1
   END;
```

A null answer is not good in my situation, I can't just use the sub-query as the main. And even if I could that would still leave the question open if the two tables were NOT the same like:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN ( ( SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE = condition ) IS NULL ) THEN
      SELECT 'No result'::varchar
   ELSE
      SELECT
         val_1,
         val_2,
         val_3
      FROM
         table_2    --TABLE REPLACED!
   END;
```

As CASE-WHEN only works for one column it would be horrifying to have 20 of them with the same condition. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can't return either 1 column or 3 columns depending on a condition. Your result set, through either execution path, would need to be the same shape. Is there any reason why `SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table1 WHERE condition` wouldn't work? Or in your second example `SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table2 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE condition);` wouldn't work? Returning the literal string in a single row/column of `'no results'` seems like it's solving a problem that shouldn't need to be solved.

Comment: In other words, this feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/438222). Could you explain more about what you are trying to solve with this pattern?

Comment: If you don't want NULL values and want to replace them with "No result", then you can use COALESCE to replace NULL with whatever you want. Or maybe I don't understand the problem correctly. Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: The problem is that we have a data browser dialog that uses sql queries. The way this dialog is used in this certain situation does not allow to "pre-check" the query result so it gets shown always. We have two tables, let's call them 'table' and 'table_log'. On delete or update (NOT on insert), the change from 'table' gets stored in 'table_log' as a new entry through a trigger function. I need to show the data from 'table_log' to the user.

Comment: If there has been no change, I want to make sure that they don't think the dialog is not loading up by clearly declaring in a row that there hasn't been any changes. (instead of having an empty dialog)
So the example could've said 'no changes done' instead of 'no result'. Kinda bad wording from me.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to SELECT the table_log and if the result is not NULL show it to the client and if it is NULL show a message?

I created a fake table for testing. What you are looking for is the last SELECT-statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_log;

CREATE TEMP TABLE table_log (
    id INTEGER
    ,log_info VARCHAR)
;

INSERT INTO table_log VALUES
    (1, 'test_entry')
;

ANALYZE table_log;

SELECT
  COALESCE(b.log_info, 'No changes done!') AS log_info
FROM
  (SELECT 'Fake-Data') a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_log WHERE id = 1) b ON (1=1);
```

If the given id = 1, you get the result, if it is something else (because it is not in the test-table) the premade message is given.

Here is a link to the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1e27dcd15dd6f709f58cd94500cb3b48).

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like that this dialog can't even handle anything else then simple SELECTs. My bad, could've assess the situation better so I could define the problem perfectly. Now I feel ashamed for posing a question without knowing all the circumstances and wasting other people's time. Sorry for that.

In the end I just made a function that returns a set of records and call that. If the log query is empty I make a record where the first field says 'No modification'. Else it shows the result. Not the nicest solution but it gets the job done.

Anyway, I appreciete the help! Thanks!